# How to wire Entity Framework Core to use invariant-enforcing constructor

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have entities on which I don't want to have a default constructor because the constructor has logic and enforces invariants.

I would like to be able to configure Entity Framework Core to use a specific constructor in a certain way.

The workaround I use for now is have purely data-oriented classes (sort of "Database DTOs") for mapping entities to database, but this is not very satisfying I would like to use my domain entity classes with EF Core.

I know that EF Core can use a constructor having parameters matching the properties. But it is too limited for some use cases. For instance, I have an entity which implements the State design pattern, meaning when retrieved from the database, a state class must be recreated from a string using a factory. EF Core can't figure that on its own and I've not yet a way to configure how entities are constructed when reconstituted from the database.

Do you know if it is possible in EF Core ?

Thanks you in advance,

Comment: Have you tried [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)?

Comment: *purely data-oriented classes for mapping entities to database* -- Well, after all, the EF model is only a data access layer. Applying DDD principles to it is mixing concerns. Either way, it would help to see an example showing why the available EF constructor features don't suffice.

Comment: @GertArnold Exactly that's because I don't want to mix concerns by contaminating my entities with DAL concerns that I rely on sort of "database DTOs" but this cause a bit of redundancy and I'd like to reuse the same class but being able to tell EF precisly how to use it. I'm adding an example of limitation to my post.